# why won't my element stay centred at all times?

Tags: html, css

I need my div with the id "splashlogo" to stay centred of my document at all times. I have tried so many different things but not sure why its not working. Can anyone help?

```css
.splashscreenlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...and see the [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/17300) to that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

Say for example if your image height is 100px and image width is 100px you can always center it like this

```
<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo" width=655 height=138>
  </div>
</div>

.splashscreenlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
    margin-top: -69px;
    margin-left: -327.5px
}
```

[Refer Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wrhbuwf/2/)

Comment: my image is 655px(wide) by 138px(tall)?

Comment: I have edited refer the fiddle and try it locally since the fiddle area is too small it will not look exactly check it out and let me know

Answer (score 1):

Considering the div has display as block you can use something like this

```
<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <center>
  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo">
  </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Or Something Like This

```
<div class="splashscreenlogo" style="text-align:center">

  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo">
  </div>

</div>
```

Or Something Like This

```
<div class="splashscreenlogo" style="margin:0 auto">

  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="logo_splashscreen.png" alt="Splashscreen logo">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The top one was great however it only sat centred horizontally. Do I need to put something so it stay centred vertically too?

Comment: <center style='vertical-align:middle'>.  To use this you div splashscreen should have height more than center which has the image

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full splash screen, which it sounds like you do, I would use the transform trick.

The important thing here is that this solution does not need to know the size of your splash image- **you don't need to change your CSS to accommodate a differently sized splash image.**

The CSS is quite simple for this- basically you position the upper left corner absolutely at 50%, 50%; then transform the image by half of it's width and height to effectively move the center of the object to that window midpoint.

```css
#splashlogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}


/* Page styling, ignore this */
body {
  background-color: #bada55; }
img {
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); }
```

```html
<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <div id="splashlogo">
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/300/300" alt="Splashscreen logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your absolute div is within a relative container first then.

```css
#splashlogo {
  position:relative;
}

.splashscreenlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width:*yourwidth*
  height:*yourheight*
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

You will also want some width & height in there for the absolute method.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use margin: 0 auto or you can also use left: 50%. This is for horizontal centering. For vertical centering you can use top: 50% or line-height.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the `slapshlogo` centered, both horizontally and vertically under most circumstances, **even on vertical re-size**.

```css
.splashscreenlogo {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff; /*#fff for white background*/
  position: absolute;
  /*margin property shorthand notation*/
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
#splashlogo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff; /*#fff for white background*/
  position: absolute;
  /*margin property shorthand notation*/
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="splashscreenlogo">
  <img id="splashlogo" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/o/i/x/2/k/G/ink-splash-with-drops-black-hi.png" alt="Splashscreen logo">
</div>
```

**source:
[How to Center Anything With CSS](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/)**